# Django model DateField: How to ensure a two-digit year is saved as "19xx"?

Tags: python, django

I have a form that takes a user's birthdate. By default, Django accepts three input formats for dates, including MM/DD/YY. However if I enter something like 02/13/45, it saves as 02/13/2045. I've looked through the places I expected to find some threads in the docs but still nothing. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Could it be as simple as checking the input, and if the year is in the future, subtract 1000? Been a bit since i've messed with django forms

Comment: @SuperStew Here I was wondering why I can't find a dozen threads answering this very obvious, common problem...thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateField just [uses the `datetime.strptime` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/forms/fields.py#L435), which in turn uses [the underlying C `strftime` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior); there's no way to change the way it parses a two-digit year. As mentioned in the comment, probably the best way to do this is to check if it's in the future, then subtract 100.

```
def clean_birthdate(self):
    birthdate = self.cleaned_data('birthdate')
    if birthdate > datetime.datetime.today():
        birthdate = birthdate.replace(year=(birthdate.year-100))
    return birthdate
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and am getting `TypeError: unorderable types`. Could this be because at this point in the process `birthdate` is still a string and hasn't been converted to a date object yet?

Comment: Can you show the full error? The point of `cleaned_data` is that it should contain data that is already cleaned, ie converted to the correct type, hence the name.

Comment: Sure, here's the error: https://pastebin.com/7S8ueXTE

And my code: https://pastebin.com/aVssUfE0

Comment: Okay I got it to work; I think I was implementing your solution incorrectly/somehow failing to make it conform to my project's needs. I also get confused around whether to include parentheses when working with `date` and `datetime` objects so I had to monkey with that a bit. Here's what finally worked: https://pastebin.com/L9nZzwms

Thank you so much!!